# Button doesn't appear. Discord.js + Node.JS

Tags: node.js, button, discord.js

i'm trying to build a bot who automatically sends a webhook with some writes and a button, but the last is not appearing

I wanna see the button, XD. Already tried many things.

```
const {ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, EmbedBuilder, WebhookClient, Events} = require('discord.js');
const webhookClient = new WebhookClient({url: "webhook link"})

const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setTitle('informations')
    .setColor('#FF5733');

const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
.addComponents(
    new ButtonBuilder()
    .setCustomId('primary')
    .setLabel('Click')
    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)
);

webhookClient.send({
    username: 'Cool BOT',
    avatarURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png',
    embeds: [embed],
    components: [row]
});
```

Comment: I don't think discord lets webhooks have buttons.

Comment: Yes, they let. If they don't let, it'll not exist on the discord.js. Link buttons are the most used.

Comment: Well then you have to set the button style to `link`, and set a url instead of a button ID

Comment: I tried it too, but the button still doesn't appear. I don't know what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that user generated webhooks can't display buttons, to make it work you would have to use a webhook that was created by a bot.

Check here for reference: https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/7097#issuecomment-991301509

Something like this should work:

```js
const { ActionRowBuilder, ButtonBuilder, ButtonStyle, EmbedBuilder, WebhookClient, Events, Client, IntentsBitField, } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({

  intents: [IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds, IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages, IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildWebhooks],

});

const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
  .setTitle('informations')
  .setColor('#FF5733');

const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
  .addComponents(
    new ButtonBuilder()
      .setLabel('Click')
      .setURL('https://google.com')
      .setStyle(5)
  );


client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('Ready!');
  client.guilds.cache.get(guildID).channels.cache.get(channelID).createWebhook({ name: 'Cool BOT', avatar: 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png' }).then(webhook => {
  webhook.send({
    username: 'Cool BOT',
    avatarURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png',
    embeds: [embed],
    components: [row]
  });
});
});




client.login(TOKEN);
```

I hope this solves your problem. Please let me know if you have any further questions

Comment: I tried to use it, but it's appearing 'invalid token'. I got the last part of https://discord.com/api/..., so I think the token is valid.